# Android update UI from Handler

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I know, there are tons of question like this at stackoverflow, and other places on the net, but after i've read a lot of them, and the official android handler documentation, i really do not understand how is it works.

The concept of the game is, players should guess out a number.

What i want to do?
I have 4 players, 3 are robots, 1 is human (me).
I made 4 slots (just views) on the UI, and put images and textviews into them.

The goal is to iterate through on the 4 player, and if it is a robot, then wait a little (random), and update its slot text, and jump to the next player.

If is it a human, show some buttons, waiting until player push one, and hide buttons.

If there are more robot players after the human, then just do what i described above about robots.

Ok, i have a code, and it seems it is works, especially when i am in debug mode, but when i just run it on my phone, sometimes things happens, before it should.

For example, the order of the players are:
Robot 1, Robot2, Human, Robot3.

Robot 1 is update its text, but for some reason Robot 2 not, and human comes, wait while i pushed a button, and Robot 3 update also.

When i tried to log, and not debug, i see, the program is totally confused.

Ok, so the code:
I have a runnable engine, what implements runnable:

```
 ...
 public abstract void update();

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (isRunning) {
        if (!isComplete) {
            update();
        }
        isComplete = true;
    }

}
...
```

and this is the activity, what is extends the code above.

```
    private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // update your view here
        if (msg.what == ROBOT_GUESS) {
            activeSlot.setSlotGuess();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Robot update: " + activeSlot.getPlayerId());
        } else if (msg.what == HUMAN_GUESS) {
            buttonsContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Human buttons");
        } else if (msg.what == HUMAN_HAS_GUESSED) {
            buttonsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            activeSlot.setSlotGuess();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Human buttons removed");
        }
    }
};

private OnClickListener playerGuessClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your guess: " + v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        activeSlot.getPlayer().setGuess(v.getId());
        isPlayerGuessed = true;
    }
};

@Override
public void update() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Update");

    for (Slot slot : slots) {
        SnobliPlayer player = slot.getPlayer();
        if (player.getType() != PlayerTypes.HUMAN.getTypeValue()) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "This is a robot");
            // This player doesn't hide yet. He should hide.
            // And it should be a Robot player
            player.guess();
            try {
                // Waiting some time between 1 - 3 second.
                Random random = new Random();
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(2000) + 1000);
                Log.d("UPDATE", String.valueOf("ROBOT GUESS"));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            activeSlot = slot;
            messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(ROBOT_GUESS);

        } else {
            // Now the human player comes.
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "I am the player");
            activeSlot = slot;
            messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(HUMAN_GUESS);
            while (!isPlayerGuessed) {
                // Do nothing
            }
            messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(HUMAN_HAS_GUESSED);

        }

    }

}
```

Why is it happen, and how can i do that, the players wait each others guessing?

Thank you.

Comment: After every sendemptyMessage, i've inserted a code with the proper value, and it seems, it solved my problem, but i am sure, this is not the way how it should work: while (messageHandler.hasMessages(ROBOT_GUESS)) {
     // Do nothing
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you have here is a threading issue...

> For example, the order of the players are: Robot 1, Robot2, Human, Robot3

You said that Robot2 got skipped.  This is because the for loop in your update method does not wait for your handler to finish executing, since they are on separate threads.  After Robot2 makes a move, the human turn is next and you call

```
activeSlot = slot;
messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(HUMAN_GUESS);
```

The problem is... You don't know for sure that the handler has already called

```
activeSlot.setSlotGuess();
```

for the last robot guess.. So when it is the human's turn, the human sets the activeSlot and you do not know if Robot2 ever got the chance to set its guess. It would be better to wait to advance the turn until the handler is done using the activeSlot object.

You could do something like this..

```
for (Slot slot : slots) {

     // at the end of your for loop..
     synchronized (activeSlot) {
         activeSlot.wait();
     }

}
```

And then after the if statement in your handler...

```
synchronized (activeSlot) {
    activeSlot.notify();
}
```

This will make sure the handler is finished using the activeSlot object before you set it again in the next turn.

Comment: thank you so much. after, when i wrote this post, i just played a little with the messageHandler, and i saw, there are several methods, like wait, and when i read the documentation, i saw, there are notify method also, so that will be the solution. thank you so much.

Comment: i've implemented the code what you suggested me, and it works like a charm. thank you very much again. Now i understood the using of thread of a handler.